# OOP initialisation strategy

Tags: oop, constructor

I often need to decide between these two strategies for the object design:

1. An object that is fully initialised and ready to use after its construction. The constructor often requires a complex list of parameters, hence the object initialisation is nontrivial. All objects having it as a member variable will also need nontrivial constructors. This may lead to code whose complexity is concentrated at object constructors, often making the code hard to follow.
2. An object with default constructor. The object variables are set individually by means of `setter methods`. This approach has the disadvantage that most methods need to check whether the object is fully initialized, hence complicating the code.

What is your personal preference between the two, and how do you decide when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if a constructor is getting too bloated it's time to split up your object in more different, smaller objects. This might be impossible in some rare cases, but in most cases it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

If a constructor takes many arguments — you call this non-trivial object initialisation — and you don't want to split up your class into smaller ones, then one alternative is to put the parameters into a [Parameter Object](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) and then only pass that object to the constructor.

Second, I believe that you should distinguish between...

- object properties that absolutely must be set if the object is supposed to do its work, and there is no sensible default value. These properties should be initialised via a constructor parameter.
- object properties that can be set optionally, or overridden, by the user. While you might initialise such properties in the constructor, you don't have to have a separate constructor parameter for them. Instead, you might assign a sensible default value to them that still can be overridden by the user through a setter method.

There is also an alternative to the first type of properties (those that must absolutely have a user-provided value): properties which are provided through overriding an abstract getter in a derived class:

```java
abstract class ComplicatedFoo {
    protected abstract T getSomeDependency(); // replaces required ctor parameter
}
```

**P.S.:** The book ["Dependency Injection" by Dhanji R. Prasanna (Manning Publications)](http://manning.com/prasanna/) gives a good overview of the various ways how to initialise an object.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.
Huge parameter lists indicates the object does too much. Lots of properties that need to be set before the object can have a valid and useful output indicates it does too much.
So neither approach is a solution as far as I'm concerned.

There are lots of ways to break these things up, but outside of a specific scenario, the only rule is, "It needs doing".

Aggregation into other objects, "controller" classes, various communicator patterns. Are some categories first class objects, can some be hidden in the implementation.

I don't accept that the two options you present are the only ones, except possibly from a pragmatic point of view in terms of getting the code out of the door. Which one I was then forced to choose, would simply depend on how many calls to the constructor with different parameters the code required, versus how much validation would be needed to confirm all the properties were set, and possibly the impact on unit tests, which because the object is a mess would be unwieldy or limited.

Answer (score -1):

It's always good to initialize all your variables in the constructor, but to a default value. If it is difficult to get the value of the variable (for example, you have to call some function somewhere to get that value), you may set that value to an invalid one and then later you set the correct value.

It is not a good idea to make the constructor so complex, because you can't return an error in the constructor (I don't know if it is ok to throw an exception in the constructor or not, because I particulary don't like trhowing exceptions anywhere). Also, you can't call virtual functions there, and so on.

An approach I like when the construction of the class is complex is to create an "init" function. Then I can do something like:

```
Person::Person()
{
    age = -1;
    ...
}

int Person::Init()
{
    age = functionThatReturnsTheAgeFromSomeDB();
    if (age == -1 )
    {
        return DB_ERROR;
    }
    ...
}
```

And so on.

Comment: -1 for splitting your ctor into two parts (the ctor itself, and `Init`). IMHO this goes against what a constructor is meant for: putting the object in a valid state. Granted, the ctor shouldn't do too much work, so if you can't easily determine a value for `age`, then pass a "functor" object to the ctor which, when later invoked, produces the value for `age`. Perhaps even remove `age` altogether in favor of such a method. But *don't* introduce another obligatory `Init` method, which is really just a continuation of the ctor. (And use exceptions instead of "magic" return values.)

Comment: (An added bonus of replacing `functionThatReturnsTheAgeFromSomeDB` with a factory method passed e.g. to the object ctor is that you are removing a hidden dependency on some DB, thereby making your class design more transparent and easier to test.)

Comment: Many safety critical coding standards (such as JSF++ and Misra) avoid using exceptions. Anyways, if you don't like to use an "Init" function, why are you suggesting the usage of exceptions? What would he do with an exception in the constructor? Consructors cannot trow exceptions, so that's another reason to have an "init" function

Comment: I don't quite understand the connections you are making. Let me address two points: **1.** Just because exceptions are best avoided in *some* situations doesn't mean they're inappropriate everywhere! So let's discuss the general case, not _"many safety critical coding standards"_. **2.** Also keep in mind that the OP asked a language-agnostic question. Yet some of the most popular OO languages out there (Java, C++, C#) definitely *do* allow exceptions to be thrown from the ctor; In fact, it's the standard way of signalling that the ctor has failed to construct a valid object.

Comment: **3.** I am not so much recommending exceptions as I am recommending against splitting the ctor into two pieces; because after the ctor has returned and before `Init` has been called, your object will likely be in some half-formed, undefined state. Each other member function has to be able to deal with this, if the user of your class forgot to call `Init` first. So why have the `Init` method at all, why not just do all the relevant work in the ctor? (And this does *not* mean having to abandon lazy initialization of some fields.)

Comment: Nope, C++ doesn't allow that. As a C++ programmer, I'm pointing the solution for this language. There may be better solutions for other languages, great, but that doesn't make my answer wrong.

Comment: Are you sure? `class Foo { public: Foo() { throw 42; } };` compiles just fine for me. Please read this C++ FAQ: [How can I handle a constructor that fails?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors-can-throw.html). Note the third sentence: _"The best way to signal constructor failure is therefore to throw an exception."_